# UK Self-Employed Income Support Scheme (SEISS) eligibility

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, covid-19, tax-residency

Will the fact that I have not been in the UK since 26th of June affect my eligibility for the third and fourth SEISS grants?

My situation:

- I have been unable to work due to COVID since March.
- I have claimed and received the first and second SEISS grants.
- I want to claim the third and fourth grants covering November 2020 to April 2021.
- My intention is to trade and pay UK income tax in the 2020/21 tax year.
- I have been living outside of the UK since 26th of June.